# How can I target the broadest range of Android devices with cordova-android for Apache Cordova?

Tags: cordova, cordova-android

When browsing https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/index.html I can see cordova-android version 8 targeting Android API levels 19-28, but I want to run the resulting Cordova application on devices supporting API level 14, therefore I was looking to install version 5 of Apache Cordova, but from the documentation it is not clear how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Please be aware that the Google Play Store has introduced a requirement that new and updated Android applications uploaded are targeting the latest two released versions of Android, see here: https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/target-sdk. The application may run on older versions of Android if it is carefully designed and it uses the following setting: minimum sdk version.

But the cordova-android pluging, while having support for the new required API levels in its latest version 8, has dropped support for API levels older than 19. Therefore you might be able to download an older version of cordova-android and build an app running on APIs lower than 19 but it would be useless in trying to build an app that can be uploaded to Google Play.